# Is there a simple process-based parallel map for python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, smp

I'm looking for a simple process-based parallel map for python, that is, a function

```
parmap(function,[data])
```

that would run function on each element of [data] on a different process (well, on a different core, but AFAIK, the only way to run stuff on different cores in python is to start multiple interpreters), and return a list of results.

Does something like this exist? I would like something **simple**, so a simple module would be nice. Of course, if no such thing exists, I will settle for a big library :-/

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I seems like what you need is the [map method in multiprocessing.Pool()](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map):

> **map(func, iterable[, chunksize])**
>
> ```
> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only
> one iterable argument though). It blocks till the result is ready.
>
> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the 
> process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be 
> specified by setting chunksize to a positive integ
> ```

For example, if you wanted to map this function:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

to range(10), you could do it using the built-in map() function:

```
map(f, range(10))
```

or using a multiprocessing.Pool() object's method map():

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
print pool.map(f, range(10))
```

Comment: If you're invoking this from a long-lived program, make sure to call `pool.close` (ideally in the `finally` block of an enclosing `try/finally`). Otherwise the pool may fail to clean up child processes and you can end up with zombie processes. See http://bugs.python.org/issue19675

Comment: @rogueleaderr Wouldn't it be more idiomatic to use `with`?

Comment: Good point @CodeMonkey! The first example on the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) uses `with` so that should handle the cleanup nicely.

Comment: `PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x121572bf8>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed` how come it can't work `lambda`?

Comment: I found here a really good example a little bit more complicated that the previous one: http://blog.adeel.io/2016/11/06/parallelize-pandas-map-or-apply/

Comment: @O.rka I guess pickle is used for communication to other processes, but lambdas are unnamed so can't be pickled.

Answer (score 15):

Python3's Pool class has a map() method and that's all you need to parallelize map:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool() as P:
    xtransList = P.map(some_func, a_list)
```

Using `with Pool() as P` is similar to a process pool and will execute each item in the list in parallel. You can provide the number of cores:

```
with Pool(processes=4) as P:
```

Answer (score 14):

This can be done elegantly with [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), a system that allows you to easily parallelize and distribute your Python code.

To parallelize your example, you'd need to define your map function with the `@ray.remote` decorator, and then invoke it with `.remote`. This will ensure that every instance of the remote function will executed in a different process.

```
import time
import ray

ray.init()

# Define the function you want to apply map on, as remote function. 
@ray.remote
def f(x):
    # Do some work...
    time.sleep(1)
    return x*x

# Define a helper parmap(f, list) function.
# This function executes a copy of f() on each element in "list".
# Each copy of f() runs in a different process.
# Note f.remote(x) returns a future of its result (i.e., 
# an identifier of the result) rather than the result itself.  
def parmap(f, list):
    return [f.remote(x) for x in list]

# Call parmap() on a list consisting of first 5 integers.
result_ids = parmap(f, range(1, 6))

# Get the results
results = ray.get(result_ids)
print(results)
```

This will print:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

and it will finish in approximately `len(list)/p` (rounded up the nearest integer) where `p` is number of cores on your machine. Assuming a machine with 2 cores, our example will execute in `5/2` rounded up, i.e, in approximately `3` sec.

There are a number of advantages of using Ray over the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. In particular, the **same code** will run on a single machine as well as on a cluster of machines. For more advantages of Ray see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python/48177988#48177988).

Answer (score 7):

For those who looking for Python equivalent of R's mclapply(), here is my implementation. It is an improvement of the following two examples:

- "[Parallelize Pandas map() or apply()](http://blog.adeel.io/2016/11/06/parallelize-pandas-map-or-apply/)", as mentioned by @Rafael
  Valero.
- [How to apply map to functions with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834960/how-to-do-multiple-arguments-to-map-function-where-one-remains-the-same-in-pytho).

It can be apply to map functions with single or multiple arguments.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse
import functools, multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, U=None, V=None):

    #blockSize = 5000
    num_partitions = 5 # int( np.ceil(df.shape[0]*(1.0/blockSize)) )
    blocks = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)

    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    if V is not None and U is not None:
        # apply func with multiple arguments to dataframe (i.e. involves multiple columns)
        df = pd.concat(pool.map(functools.partial(func, U=U, V=V), blocks))
    else:
        # apply func with one argument to dataframe (i.e. involves single column)
        df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, blocks))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return df

def square(x):
    return x**2

def test_func(data):
    print("Process working on: ", data.shape)
    data["squareV"] = data["testV"].apply(square)
    return data

def vecProd(row, U, V):
    return np.sum( np.multiply(U[int(row["obsI"]),:], V[int(row["obsJ"]),:]) )

def mProd_func(data, U, V):
    data["predV"] = data.apply( lambda row: vecProd(row, U, V), axis=1 )
    return data

def generate_simulated_data():

    N, D, nnz, K = [302, 184, 5000, 5]
    I = np.random.choice(N, size=nnz, replace=True)
    J = np.random.choice(D, size=nnz, replace=True)
    vals = np.random.sample(nnz)

    sparseY = sparse.csc_matrix((vals, (I, J)), shape=[N, D])

    # Generate parameters U and V which could be used to reconstruct the matrix Y
    U = np.random.sample(N*K).reshape([N,K])
    V = np.random.sample(D*K).reshape([D,K])

    return sparseY, U, V

def main():
    Y, U, V = generate_simulated_data()

    # find row, column indices and obvseved values for sparse matrix Y
    (testI, testJ, testV) = sparse.find(Y)

    colNames = ["obsI", "obsJ", "testV", "predV", "squareV"]
    dtypes = {"obsI":int, "obsJ":int, "testV":float, "predV":float, "squareV": float}

    obsValDF = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(testV), len(colNames))), columns=colNames)
    obsValDF["obsI"] = testI
    obsValDF["obsJ"] = testJ
    obsValDF["testV"] = testV
    obsValDF = obsValDF.astype(dtype=dtypes)

    print("Y.shape: {!s}, #obsVals: {}, obsValDF.shape: {!s}".format(Y.shape, len(testV), obsValDF.shape))

    # calculate the square of testVals    
    obsValDF = parallelize_dataframe(obsValDF, test_func)

    # reconstruct prediction of testVals using parameters U and V
    obsValDF = parallelize_dataframe(obsValDF, mProd_func, U, V)

    print("obsValDF.shape after reconstruction: {!s}".format(obsValDF.shape))
    print("First 5 elements of obsValDF:\n", obsValDF.iloc[:5,:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but just in case, I wrote a tool to make this super, super easy called [parmapper](https://github.com/Jwink3101/parmapper) (I actually call it parmap in my use but the name was taken).

It handles a lot of the setup and deconstruction of processes and adds tons of features. In rough order of importance

- Can take lambda and other unpickleable functions
- Can apply starmap and other similar call methods to make it very easy to directly use.
- Can split amongst both threads and/or processes
- Includes features such as progress bars

It does incur a small cost but for most uses, that is negligible.

I hope you find it useful.

(Note: It, like `map` in Python 3+, returns an iterable so if you expect all results to pass through it immediately, use `list()`)