# How to do multiple arguments to map function where one remains the same

Tags: python

Let's say we have a function `add` as follows

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

we want to apply map function for an array

```
map(add, [1, 2, 3], 2)
```

The semantics are I want to add 2 to every element of the array. But the `map` function requires a list in the third argument as well.

**Note:** I am putting the `add` example for simplicity. My original function is much more complicated. And of course option of setting the default value of `y` in `add` function is out of question as it will be changed for every call.

Comment: this is exactly the same as in Lisp: `map(add,[1,2,3],[2]*3)`  in general `map` takes in a function as its first argument, and if this function takes **K** argument, you have to follow up with **K** iterable: `addTriple(a,b,c) -> map(addTriple,[...],[...],[...])`

Comment: would be great to have maplist/2-like thing from prolog

Answer (score 268, accepted):

One option is a list comprehension:

```
[add(x, 2) for x in [1, 2, 3]]
```

More options:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

import functools
map(functools.partial(add, y=2), a)

import itertools
map(add, a, itertools.repeat(2, len(a)))
```

Comment: yup, but how fast is it in comparison to map function?

Comment: @Shan: Very similar, especially if `add()` is a non-trivial function

Comment: @Shan: list comprehensions are about 15% faster on my box.

Comment: I am using map function because my data set id very large and python loops are taking very long...

Comment: @Shan: Take a look at NumPy in this case.  If this really is an issue for you, the speed difference between list comprehensions and `map()` won't help either way.

Comment: @Shan: As I said before, have a look at NumPy.  It might help speeding up loops conderably, provided they can be vectorised.

Comment: Why are you passing `len(a)` to the `repeat`? Just use an infinite iterator; it's shorter, cheaper, and exactly what the docs suggest as the primary use for `repeat`.

Comment: @abarnert: It's unclear whether the OP is using Python 2 or 3.  To make sure the example works in Python 2, I included the parameter. (Note that `map()` behaves like `zip_longest()` in Python 2, while it behaves like `zip()` in Python 3.)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `partial`, it's a great replacement for using `starmap` and repeat for passing multiple constants to a function along with a single list of dynamic values.

Answer (score 110):

The docs explicitly suggest this is the main use for [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

> Make an iterator that returns object over and over again. Runs indefinitely unless the times argument is specified. Used as argument to [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for invariant parameters to the called function. Also used with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to create an invariant part of a tuple record.

And there's no reason for pass `len([1,2,3])` as the `times` argument; `map` stops as soon as the first iterable is consumed, so an infinite iterable is perfectly fine:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> list(map(add, [1,2,3], repeat(4)))
[5, 6, 7]
```

In fact, this is equivalent to the example for `repeat` in the docs:

```
>>> list(map(pow, range(10), repeat(2)))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

This makes for a nice lazy-functional-language-y solution that's also perfectly readable in Python-iterator terms.

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer.  It extends to any number of parameters, of course, with some constant and others lists or generators. E.g.: `def f(x,y,z): \\  return '.'.join([x,y,z])` and then: `list(map(f, list('abc'), repeat('foo'), list('defgh')))` returns `['a.foo.d', 'b.foo.e', 'c.foo.f']`.

Comment: In Python 2, it's necessary to provide the length argument to `repeat()`, since `map()` will run until the _longest_ iterator is exhausted in that version of Python, filling in `None` for all missing values.  Saying that "there's not reason" to pass the parameter is wrong.

Comment: @SvenMarnach 's comment is not minor: [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) 's behaviour varies drastically!

Comment: Very neat and readable!

Answer (score 46):

Use a list comprehension.

```
[x + 2 for x in [1, 2, 3]]
```

If you *really*, *really*, *really* want to use `map`, give it an anonymous function as the first argument:

```
map(lambda x: x + 2, [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 30):

Map can contain multiple arguments, the standard way is

```
map(add, a, b)
```

In your question, it should be

```
map(add, a, [2]*len(a))
```

Comment: Not sure what his question meant to but i think add accept 2 value and those 2 are not fixed and should come from user like arg1 is coming. so in this case how we should call add(x, y) under map?

Answer (score 22):

The correct answer is simpler than you think.
Simply do:

```
map(add, [(x, 2) for x in [1,2,3]])
```

And change the implementation of add to take a tuple i.e

```
def add(t):
   x, y = t
   return x+y
```

This can handle any complicated use case where both add parameters are dynamic.

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes I resolved similar situations (such as using [pandas.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method) using [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)

In order to use them, you define a function which dynamically defines and returns a wrapper for your function, effectively making one of the parameters a constant.

Something like this:

```
def add(x, y):
   return x + y

def add_constant(y):
    def f(x):
        return add(x, y)
    return f
```

Then, `add_constant(y)` returns a function which can be used to add `y` to any given value:

```
>>> add_constant(2)(3)
5
```

Which allows you to use it in any situation where parameters are given one at a time:

```
>>> map(add_constant(2), [1,2,3])
[3, 4, 5]
```

**edit**

If you do not want to have to write the closure function somewhere else, you always have the possibility to build it on the fly using a lambda function:

```
>>> map(lambda x: add(x, 2), [1, 2, 3])
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 14):

If you have it available, I would consider using numpy. It's very fast for these types of operations:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.array([1,2,3]) + 2
array([3, 4, 5])
```

This is assuming your real application is doing mathematical operations (that can be vectorized).

Answer (score 11):

If you really really need to use map function (like my class assignment here...), you could use a wrapper function with 1 argument, passing the rest to the original one in its body; i.e. :

```
extraArguments = value
def myFunc(arg):
    # call the target function
    return Func(arg, extraArguments)


map(myFunc, itterable)
```

Dirty & ugly, still does the trick

Comment: A closure, I think this adds something, plus one. Similar to a partial function, as the accepted answer has.

Comment: `myFunc` needs to `return Func(arg, extraArguments)`

Comment: I stand corrected @PM2Ring, that's true; updated the code.

Comment: where is Func defined? because I am getting a name error for Func

Comment: `Func` is the name of your original function - for OP tight would be `add` for example

Answer (score 9):

I believe starmap is what you need:

```
from itertools import starmap


def test(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z

list(starmap(test, [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def func(a, b, c, d):
 return a + b * c % d
```

```
map(lambda x: func(*x), [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]])
```

By wrapping the function call with a lambda and using the star unpack, you can do map with arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: lambda is very slow, use functools instead

Comment: I's quite mysterious you got so much upvotes by not answering the question, which is about using a constant argument for the function referenced in `map`. Let me add mine just for the fun. Here is a [valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27025330/774575).

Answer (score 2):

You can include lambda along with map:

```
list(map(lambda a: a+2, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass multiple arguments to a `map` function.

```
def q(x,y):
    return x*y

print map (q,range(0,10),range(10,20))
```

Here **q** is function with multiple argument that **map()** calls.
Make sure, the length of both the ranges i.e.

```
len (range(a,a')) and len (range(b,b')) are equal.
```

Answer (score 1):

In :`nums = [1, 2, 3]`

In :`map(add, nums, [2]*len(nums))`

Out:`[3, 4, 5]`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
results = []
for x in [1,2,3]:
    z = add(x,2)
    ...
    results += [f(z,x,y)]
```

This format is very useful when calling multiple functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#multi argument

def joke(r):
     if len(r)==2:
          x, y = r
          return x + y
     elif len(r)==3:
           x,y,z=r
           return x+y+z

#using map

    print(list(map(joke,[[2,3],[3,4,5]])))
```

output = [6,12]

if the case like above and just want use function

```
def add(x,y):
    ar =[]
    for xx in x:
         ar.append(xx+y)
    return ar
print(list(map(add,[[3,2,4]],[2]))[0])
output = [5,4,6]
```

Note: you can modified as you want.