# Add a fix argument in map - Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, loops, dns

I am trying to iterate on a method and passing others arguments that the method needs.
To do so, I think my best shot is to use map() method.

More precisely, I need performs several dns requests (A / AAAA / NS / MX) on several FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name, ie: www.mywebsite.com).

As requests can wait few seconds waiting for an answer, I am using threads to compensate.

Here is my actual code :

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        for fqdn in fqdn_list:
            future_01 = executor.submit(get_dns_query, fqdn, 'A')
            future_02 = executor.submit(get_dns_query, fqdn, 'AAAA')

            ip = future_01.result()
            ipv6 = future_02.result()
```

Now what I think is best:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        ip = executor.map(get_dns_query, fqdn, 'A')
        ipv6 = executor.submit(get_dns_query, fqdn, 'AAAA')
```

**get_dns_query** will perform a dns request and requires **FQDN** and **RDTYPE** (A / AAAA / NS / MX)

I want **map()** to iterate on **FQDN** and I also want to be able to pass **RDTYPE** as a normal argument.

So far, I understood that it is not the purpose of map. But solutions seems to exist:
[Functools or Itertools solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834960/how-to-do-multiple-arguments-to-map-function-where-one-remains-the-same-in-pytho)

Unfortunately, I am not able to understand them and if they are applicable to my case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution could work for you :

```
import functools


fqdn_list = ['www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com']

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        ips = executor.map(functools.partial(get_dns_query, rdtype_freezed_arg='A'), fqdn_list)
        ipsv6 = executor.map(functools.partial(get_dns_query, rdtype_freezed_arg='AAAA'), fqdn_list)

## SOME CODE

for ip in ips:
    print(ip)


for ipv6 in ipv6s:
    print(ipv6)
```

What i did is :
'freezing' part of get_dns_query function that i imagine take 2 arguments

```
def get_dns_query(rdtype, fqdn):
# lines of code
```

mapping it along a list of dynamic args 'fqdn_list'
So it will behave like this :

```
get_dns_query(rdtype_freezed_arg='A', fqdn_list[0])
get_dns_query(rdtype_freezed_arg='A', fqdn_list[1])
# and so on ...
```

then i collect the results (n results, defined by fqdn_list.size()) on generator ips and ipv6s

and finally i iterate over them.

Observation : I didn't test it.

EDIT : I used 'rdtype_freezed_arg' as the arg name for didactical purpose, you should use the name of the arg used in the function declaration.

Comment: @steackfrite My answer helped you? If possible, give me a feedback in the comments please.

Comment: Thanks man, that's exactly what I want.
The result send by executor.map() is: generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at 0x7f9286451ad0>. I should be able to iterate on it with a for loop? (As you pointed in your response).

Comment: I think you should be able to do that with the syntax  
for generator_item in generator_object:
     # some code here
Could you please test it and report me if it's correct? In that case, please rate my answer as useful/solver.
Thanks man

Comment: It worked well!
Thanks again (rating should come after moderation, seems like new users actions are oversee for a time)