# Pass named arguments in list comprehensions in map function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass arguments in to a function which is being mapped. Is there a way to clean this up or optimize?

```
# Map resized images
resized_imgs = tuple(map(resize_image, all_img_steps, [None for img in all_img_steps], [output_height for img in all_img_steps]))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Closely related: [How to do multiple arguments to map function where one remains the same in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10834960/4518341) I would say it's a duplicate, but there's no such thing as a tuple comprehension so it's not quite identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) instead of a map.

```
resized_imgs = tuple(resize_image(img, None, output_height) for img in all_img_steps)
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That is much more [readable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2). Learn something new every day!

Comment: @DavidAlford Yes, comprehensions are more readable, that is basically [what Guido said about `map` as well](https://developers.slashdot.org/story/13/08/25/2115204/interviews-guido-van-rossum-answers-your-questions) ;) Great minds think alike