# Python equivalent of R's mclapply()

Tags: python, r, pandas, multicore

The R package multicore has a function mclapply() which applies a specified function over a list of things and takes advantage of multiple cores. It's easy to use and results in big speed boosts.

Is there a Python equivalent? Thanks

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I don't think pandas/numpy can make use of multicores... yet. This is [being worked on](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze-core).

Comment: This isn't a single process solution and will not map to mclapply. But if you run processing functions on a single dataset that doesn't change, this helps - http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel

Comment: we should have something like this hopefully pretty soon: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3202

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is available from the map method in multiprocessing.Pool()

See this answer for more details: [Is there a simple process-based parallel map for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704401/is-there-a-simple-process-based-parallel-map-for-python)