# Pickle error when making parallel version of map function in Python using Multiprocessing

Tags: python, function, lambda, parallel-processing, pickle

I'm following the answer on [Is there a simple process-based parallel map for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704401/is-there-a-simple-process-based-parallel-map-for-python) using `Python 3.6.1`.  I'm trying to use it the same exact way as I would use the regular `map` function.  Why does this happen?  How can I create a parallel `map` function for use with `lambda`?

```
def map_parallel(func, iterable, n_jobs=-1):
    if n_jobs == -1:
        n_jobs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_jobs)
    return pool.map(func, iterable)

map_parallel(lambda x: x + 3, range(100))


PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x185284f28>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

Answer (score 0):

multiprocessing pickle objects to pass between processes. `lambda` is not serializable (See [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)); it can't be passed between processes.

You need to define a function, and pass that.

```
def add3(n):
    return n + 3

map_parallel(add3, range(100))
```

Or for this case, you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) with [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.add):

```
import functools
import operator

map_parallel(functools.partial(operator.add, 3), range(100))
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert `lambda` to a `function`?  I rarely ever use `map` with `functions` and use it on the fly with transforming iterables

Comment: @O.rka, Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25353243/2225682).