# Python 3 does inbuilt map function using parallel

Tags: python-3.x

I wonder if the built in map function splits a list in x-chunks to apply the give function in parallel (Threads)?

The docu doesnt say anything about it but I would wonder why it is not implemented like this.

```
    def map_func(x):
    '''

   :param x: 
   :return: 2x
   >>> map_func(4)
   4
   '''
    return x * x


new_list = list(map(map_func, range(1, 2 ** 25)))
print(new_list)
```

From the task manager i cannot clearly see if its done by one thread or more.

Can someone explain please if its sequential and if so, why?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: If your question is "why `map` doesn't process in parallel", well, that's either too broad or opinion based. If you want multiprocessing, import the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sequential because [`map` the higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) in general has to apply a function to data and return the results *in the same order* as the original data:

```
map(f, [1,2,3,4]) => [f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)]
```

<strike>Making it parallel will introduce the need of synchronisation, which'll defeat the purpose of parallelism.</strike>

`multiprocessing.Pool.map` is a parallel version of the built-in `map` that will split the workload into chunks and correctly organise the results.

Comment: Your last sentence is slightly misleading. `map` can be run in parallel without making it useless. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704401/is-there-a-simple-process-based-parallel-map-for-python) question and answers.

Comment: @ninesalt, well, yeah, but it still has to stitch the individual results together somehow, and that's additional work. It also can't operate on infinite iterables because it [converts the iterable to `list`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04b2a5eedac7ac0fecdafce1bda1028ee55e2aac/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L375), which is also additional work

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the reason that `map()` does not run in parallel in cpython. A parallel version of `map()` could easily reserve space for the results up front and insert the results as they became ready. I think the reason is that cpython does not support running interpreted code in parallel. Multithreading in cpython still serializes code execution (with the GIL).

Comment: @RogerDahl, yeah, two years later, I'm not a fan of this answer either. That the results have to be in the same order doesn't mean that the mapping can't be parallel: for example, the main operations in Apache Spark are `map` and `reduce`, so parallel `map` is most definitely a thing - it's just not the built-in one