# How can I split the list by one object of the list in python in an efficient way

Tags: python, list

There is one list of objects an object contain a name and a vendor
I need to separate list of object with vendor.
Same vendor objects should be in same list

How can I do so in python in an efficient way:-

List I have:

```
[
{
    name:"Ram",
    vendor:1,
},
{
    name:"Shaam",
    vendor:2
},
{
    name:"Mohan",
    vendor:1
},
{
    name:"Sohan",
    vendor:3
},
{
    name:"Aman",
    vendor:2
}
]
```

Lists I want:-

1. List-1:

```
[
{
    name:"Ram",
    vendor:1,
},
{
    name:"Mohan",
    vendor:1
}
]
```

2. List-2:

```
[
{
    name:"Shaam",
    vendor:2
},
{
    name:"Aman",
    vendor:2
}
]
```

3. List-3:

```
[
{
    name:"Sohan",
    vendor:3
}
]
```

Comment: Where did Ram come from? :)  Have you tried anything yourself?  We don't know how much you know, do you know what a `for` loop is?  Show us your best attempt and explain why it's not working for you, and we'll be able to help appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure of the efficiency of this code but I believe it outputs what you're looking for. As a note the output list will be 0 indexed, so you make sure that you subtract 1 from the vendor number to get the index.

code

```
data = [
{
    'name':"Ram",
    'vendor':1,
},
{
    'name':"Shaam",
    'vendor':2
},
{
    'name':"Mohan",
    'vendor':1
},
{
    'name':"Sohan",
    'vendor':3
},
{
    'name':"Aman",
    'vendor':2
}
]

storage = {}

for datum in data:
    name = datum['name']
    vendor = datum['vendor']
    if vendor in storage:
        storage[vendor].append(name)
    else:
        storage[vendor] = [name]

output = []

for key in sorted(storage.keys()):
    output.append([])
    for value in storage[key]:
        new_dict = {'name': value, 'vendor': key}
        output[key - 1].append(new_dict)
        
for val in output:
    print(val)
```

output

```
[{'name': 'Ram', 'vendor': 1}, {'name': 'Mohan', 'vendor': 1}]
[{'name': 'Shaam', 'vendor': 2}, {'name': 'Aman', 'vendor': 2}]
[{'name': 'Sohan', 'vendor': 3}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this(think how to store the different lists in each iteration):

```
for i in range(numOfVendors):
    yourList = [x for x in initialList if x["vendor"] == i]
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: A sequential classifier is fine, since python `map()` is also sequential.

Besides, `multiprocessing.Pool.map` may be an overkill, since it introduces inter-process communication overhead. Use this if you're sure that `data` is extremely long.

Here is my profile code:

- `sequential`: an oneliner sequential classifier
- `multi`: process based map.

```py
from funcy import print_durations
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import Pool

DATA = [
{
    'name':"Ram",
    'vendor':1,
},
{
    'name':"Shaam",
    'vendor':2
},
{
    'name':"Mohan",
    'vendor':1
},
{
    'name':"Sohan",
    'vendor':3
},
{
    'name':"Aman",
    'vendor':2
}
]

def sequential(data):
    ans = defaultdict(lambda: [])
    for d in data:
        ans[d["vendor"]].append(d)
    return dict(ans)

def multi(data, worker=10):
    def k_fold(myList, N):
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-length
        return [myList[(i*len(myList))//N:((i+1)*len(myList))//N] for i in range(N)]

    def merge_all(dicts):
        ans = defaultdict(lambda: [])
        for d in dicts:
            for k, v in d.items():
                ans[k].extend(v)
        return ans

    data = k_fold(data, worker)
    with Pool(worker) as P:
        ans = P.map(sequential, data)
    return dict(merge_all(ans))

def timing(data_size=1000):
    print("timing for data size {:.0E}".format(data_size))

    data = DATA * data_size

    @print_durations()
    def timing_seq():
        sequential(data)

    @print_durations()
    def timing_multi():
        multi(data)

    s = timing_seq()
    m = timing_multi()
    assert s == m

for i in range(3, 8):
    timing(10**i)
```

Output in my laptop, with python 3.10.2:

```
$ python test.py 
timing for data size 1E+03
  475.65 mks in timing_seq()
   36.63 ms in timing_multi()
timing for data size 1E+04
    4.52 ms in timing_seq()
   22.28 ms in timing_multi()
timing for data size 1E+05
   46.35 ms in timing_seq()
   84.26 ms in timing_multi()
timing for data size 1E+06
  459.60 ms in timing_seq()
  510.74 ms in timing_multi()
timing for data size 1E+07
    4.34 s in timing_seq()
    3.00 s in timing_multi()
```

Sadly, `multi` performs better only when data reach size of 10^7 level.

But it scales, if you give it more workers like this:

```py
# ...
# Same script

data_size = 10**7
print("timing for data size {:.0E}".format(data_size))
for i in range(1, 6):
    worker = 2 ** i
    print("worker = {}".format(worker))
    data = DATA * data_size

    @print_durations()
    def timing_multi():
        multi(data, worker)

    timing_multi()
```

Output shows the performance scales, but too many workers will introduce overhead which cancel the effect of speed up ;)

```
timing for data size 1E+07
worker = 2
    3.89 s in timing_multi()
worker = 4
    2.91 s in timing_multi()
worker = 8
    2.47 s in timing_multi()
worker = 16
    2.52 s in timing_multi()
worker = 32
    3.43 s in timing_multi()
```

Ref: [Is there a simple process-based parallel map for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704401/is-there-a-simple-process-based-parallel-map-for-python)